# C# OnReceived Event is fired twice

Tags: c#

I'm relatively new to C# and had stumbled across an issue where my onreceived event is triggered twice but the first time doesn't update the subscriber instead it only update on the second times. Below are some of the codes used in my program. Appreciate if anyone can have a look and tell me where is the cause at.

I have something like this.

```
public TCPMain()
    {
        SocketService.TCPClient.onConnected += new SocketService.TCPClient.onConnectedHandler(Client_onConnected);
        SocketService.TCPClient.onDataReceived += new SocketService.TCPClient.onDataReceivedHandler(Client_onDataReceived);
        SocketService.TCPClient.onDisconnected += new SocketService.TCPClient.onDisconnectedHandler(Client_onDisconnected);
        SocketService.TCPClient.onStatus += new SocketService.TCPClient.onStatusHandler(Client_onStatus);
        SocketService.TCPClient.onStatus2 += new SocketService.TCPClient.onStatus2Handler(Client_onStatus2);
    }

    public TCPMain(string RemoteServerIP, int RemoteServerPort, int RemoteServerPort2, string LocalIP = "", int LocalPort = 0)
    {
        this.RemoteServerIP = RemoteServerIP;
        this.RemoteServerPort = RemoteServerPort;
        this.RemoteServerPort2 = RemoteServerPort2;
        this.LocalIP = LocalIP;
        this.LocalPort = LocalPort;

        SocketService.TCPClient.onConnected += new SocketService.TCPClient.onConnectedHandler(Client_onConnected);
        SocketService.TCPClient.onDataReceived += new SocketService.TCPClient.onDataReceivedHandler(Client_onDataReceived);
        SocketService.TCPClient.onDisconnected += new SocketService.TCPClient.onDisconnectedHandler(Client_onDisconnected);
        SocketService.TCPClient.onStatus += new SocketService.TCPClient.onStatusHandler(Client_onStatus);
        SocketService.TCPClient.onStatus2 += new SocketService.TCPClient.onStatus2Handler(Client_onStatus2);
    }
```

Then I have something created on a virtual

```
    public delegate void onReceivedHandler(string Key, string value);
    public event onReceivedHandler OnReceived;

    public delegate void onDataReceivedHandler(string Message);
    public event onDataReceivedHandler onDataReceived;

    public virtual void RaiseOnDataReceived(string Message)
    {
        if (onDataReceived != null)
            onDataReceived(Message);
    }
```

And when the received event is triggered, the following function is called

```
    void Client_onDataReceived(string Message)
    {
        try
        {
            RaiseOnDataReceived(Message);
            Message = Message.TrimEnd();
            string[] _strParts = null;
        }
     }
```

When a new message arrived, the Client_onDataReceived is triggered and after that RaiseOnDataReceived is called from the TCPMain with reference to the virtual. The problem is when it reached the virtual, the onDataReceived is = null so it return back to the Client and execute the rest of the coding. The second time the event is triggered, the onDataReceived is = something but there are only one message sent at the time.

Comment: `SocketService.TCPClient` is static hence, possibility that there are multiple wirings of event on your code. Check how many instances that the `TCPMain` has, and how many times `onDataReceived ` has been subscribed to. You can put a breakpoint on `SocketService.TCPClient.onDataReceived +=` to see how many times it was called.

Comment: @JoelLegaspiEnriquez How on Earth do you know that it's static?

Comment: @DavidG, subscribing at the same object, which is possibly static could be the cause of the issue. I should have written 'possibly' as I was thinking that `SocketService` (namespace) `static class TCPClient` (class declaration) `public static event EventHandler  onDataReceived` (static event) was the way it was coded.